# MongoDB - anonymizing 600k records

Tags: scala, mongodb

I am trying to anonymize a large data set of about 600k records (removing sensitive information like email, etc.) so that it can be used for some performance tests.

I am using Scala (Casbah) with Mongo. The actual script is pretty simple and straightforward. When I run the script, the entire process starts off pretty fast - parsing 1000 records every 2-3 seconds, but it slows down tremendously and starts crawling very slowly.

I know this is pretty vague without too much details, but any idea why this is happening, and any hints on how I could speed this up?

Comment: Do have any indexes on any of the fields you are anonymizing?

Comment: can you share some output of your `mongostat` ?  are there too many write locks and page faults ?

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with the driver and not with Mongo. When I tried the same inserts in the mongo shell, it was through without breaking a sweat. How do I close this question?

Comment: Answer it yourself and accept it. It's still useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the driver and not with Mongo. When I tried the same inserts using the mongo shell, it was through without breaking a sweat.

**UPDATE**

So, I tried both approaches. Inserting into existing collection and dumping the results in a new collection. The first approach was faster for me. Of course, one should never assume this to be always true and must benchmark before choosing the first approach over the second. In both case, Mongo was very very fast (meaning - it was not taking hours to get this done). There was a problem with the Java interface I was using to connect with Mongo, which was more of a stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is your original/new approach? (`update` the original collection or `insert` into a new one)